# Instead of EZ Anchors...Epoxy and screws?

Tags: drywall

I just pulled an old TP hanger that was always loose out of my bathroom/wall.  Of course the old drywall anchors when I pulled them out left a big mess.  After several days of redo's I got the spot looking like the rest of the wall.  I say many days, because I have a knockdown/orange peel, as well as a FAUX paint finish that takes two or three passes of primer/base, and glaze to match.

I bought this cool wrought iron TP hanger from etsy, dark brown, but of course is came with two matching brown wood screws.

Today as I was looking at the giant EZ anchors(they are always so big)...I had the thought...can i just drill a small hole...put some epoxy glue or something similar into the hole...and my original screws?  or maybe even some mud...I guess I know i can..just wondering if its a waste of time, or will i get many years out of it.  I just hate to make a mess with those big white anchors..

Comment: You will almost certainly make a bigger mess trying to remove an epoxied-in screw than an anchor. And really, the mess from the anchors is usually not that hard to patch if you deal with them the right way (drill off the head, plaster over the hole, paint -- or sometimes just plaster and paint, or just leave them in place with a dab of paint).

Comment: Yeah thx...I got out my "bag" of stud finders and like i thought..no good spot....I will just use the Ez-Anchor...I guess if the "other way" was feasible I would have found something in my searches..thx.

Comment: My goal was to have something that would not work its way loose over the years..which is why i was thinking a dab of ready patch..but anyway..put the EZ's in..looks a bit crappy by I painted over the white tops.

Comment: For those of us the wrong side of the pond or otherwise not US… what on earth is a TP hanger?

Comment: toilet paper...i did not want to get banned like my football forum.

Comment: D'oh… simple once you know. I was thinking…  toothpaste, no, can't be… I guess my brain just didn't make the leap. My bad, sorry. [I was once auto-banned from FarceBork for writing 'screwed' …in a woodworking group. Big Brother may be watching, but he's clearly not understanding context.]

Comment: We talk about toilets here, so you're not going to get banned for "toilet paper".

Comment: Applying epoxy to the screws/hole then driving the screws in will simply result in a bigger chunk of drywall coming out when the holder falls off.

Answer (score 2):

**Don't** mount a TP holder, or anything that is frequently pushed, pulled, and jiggled by human hands, to drywall.   Some anchors will last longer than others especially if you are the only one using it and are gentle, but no matter which anchor you use eventually the dispenser will become loose and uneven on the wall.

- Mount it to the side of a cabinet
- Open the wall and install a backer board
- Mount a pretty routed piece of wood over the wall across two studs and the holder to that
- Buy a floor-standing TP holder
- Keep the TP on the lid of the toilet tank

If you insist on mounting to drywall, buy a dispenser that has two mounting  brackets, one at each end of the roll rather than just at one end, and where each bracket has at least two but preferably three screw holes.  Use the best possible anchor in all the holes.   Buy extra anchors and practice using the specific andchor on a scrap piece of drywall before doing it for real.   Make sure your scrap piece is the same thickness as your wall.

Comment: 4 people x 4 or more poops a day x 365 days a year...no problem!  I hear you about the free standing ones I did look at some but could not find the right size...thx anyway...I like the routed would Idea..that could look nice...

Comment: The wood "bridge" between studs could also support a shelf or other decoration, if you think just having the wood backplate would look odd.

Comment: @eaglerockdude - "free standing" We got a free standing one. In the beginning it seemed to be a good solution and looked great. We set it where it did not directly get wet, but due to the dampness/moisture in the air from people taking showers, after 6 months, the Toilet Paper Stand was rusted/corroded so bad and so completely, that it looked like we pulled it out of a lake after 15 years under water. So my point is, I still think a free standing Toilet Paper holder is/can be a great solution, make sure it's made of Stainless Steel or something that can stand up to the moisture.

Comment: @eaglerockdude 4 x 4 / day? If you're looking product recommendations, consider adding some fiber to the household diet.